How to define weak functions with Cygwin C compiler?
I'm trying to compile C code on Windows 10 using cygwin gcc-g++ 11.3.0-1 that compiles perfectly fine using a gcc-arm-none-eabi cross-compiler.
lib.h:
typedef enum
{
    SYSUTILS_RET_OK         = 0,
    SYSUTILS_RET_ERROR,
} sysutils_ret_e;

sysutils_ret_e ResetSystem(void);

lib.c:
#include "lib.h"

sysutils_ret_e __attribute__((weak)) ResetSystem(void)
{
    return SYSUTILS_RET_ERROR;
}

main.c:
#include "lib.h"

int main(void)
{
   ...
   ResetSystem();
   ...
}

Linker error: undefined reference to ResetSystem
My guess is cygwin cannot handle __attribute__((weak)) syntax but I could not find documentation that supports this suspicion.
Does anybody know what's the problem or if cygwin simply does not support this feature?
Thanks!

Is it ResetSystem as in lib.h and lib.c or SystemReset as in main.c?

How do you link it? The cross-compiler should handle this attribute just fine, unless it is built with some weird settings.

And yes, you are calling SystemReset, while elsewhere it is ResetSystem, including the error message. So it is inconsistent to say the least.

@EugeneSh. You are correct I messed up the code example. My bad, thanks for pointing that out. I've corrected it. Anyways, in my code it is consistent, this error just happened inside the post. Do you know why Cygwin seemingly cannot link weakly defined functions?

IIRC, cygwin produces windows PE files. Weak symbols are largely an ELF feature and PE files do not support them directly. In visual studio et. al. there is a [hacky?] workaround: #pragma comment(linker, "/alternatename:symbol1=symbol2") that is passed to the windows linker link.exe. If symbol1 is not defined it is resolved as symbol2. Cygwin's gcc may or may not handle this. You might have your make run a custom script that extracts these symbols and passes them on the command line to the linker.

@CraigEstey Thanks for the good workaround suggestion, although I fear that this is only supported by msvc, cygwin just ignors this pragma. Very unsatisfying that there seems to be just no mechanism for weak symbols in cygwin's c compiler, at least I couldn't find one anywhere. In fact, information is kind of scarse about the whole thing online, as if nobody else sees this as a problem, so maybe it's just me missing this feature.

AFAICT, /alternatename is a command line switch, so the pragma is just a nicety. See: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20200731-00/?p=104024 Also, note the last few footnote paragraphs on how to use a .lib file for some of the effects (instead of /alternatename).
